# how to use echo command to print string, integer value using script

Tags: bash, unix

how to add i value also in the echo command

code:

```
set date _strdt = '2015-01-01'; 
for i in {0..365} 
do 
NEXT_DATE=$(_strdt +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + $i day") 
echo "$NEXT_DATE", i 
done
```

i need a output like

```
2016-01-01,1 
2016-01-02,2 
2016-01-03,3 
2016-01-04,4 
.
.
2016-31-31,365
```

Is it possible? if yes please please share with me.

Comment: What do you think this line is supposed to do? `set date _strdt = '2015-01-01';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATE=2015-01-01 
for i in {0..364} 
do 
NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + $i day") 
echo "$NEXT_DATE","$((i+1))" 
done
```

Comment: the i value is starting from 0, if i change it as 1 in the query then it will start the date as 2016-01-02.
2016-01-01,0
2016-01-02,1
2016-01-03,2
2016-01-04,3
2016-01-05,4
2016-01-06,5
2016-01-07,6
2016-01-08,7
2016-01-09,

Comment: when i ran the below command its showing the error. please help me to fix this.
code:
#!/bin/bash
DATE=2015-01-01 
for i in {0..364} 
do 
NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + $i day") 
echo "$NEXT_DATE","$((i+1))" 
hive -e 'insert into default.sd_digit($NEXT_DATE, digit)
select $NEXT_DATE as dt, digit from default.sd_digit'
done

Comment: [cloudera@localhost ~]$ /home/cloudera/Desktop/Hive/test.sh > /home/cloudera/Desktop/Hive/test_output6.csv
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.6.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/cloudera/hive_job_log_75917f5b-7621-4ab9-b2ed-b954ccf880a8_2077392982.txt
FAILED: ParseException line 1:12 missing TABLE at 'default' near 'sd_digit' in select clause
line 1:28 cannot recognize input near '(' '$' 'NEXT_DATE' in select clause

Comment: query: #!/bin/bash DATE=2015-01-01 for i in {0..364} do NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE + $i day") echo "$NEXT_DATE","$((i+1))" hive -e 'insert into default.sd_digit($NEXT_DATE, digit) select $NEXT_DATE as dt, digit from default.sd_digit' done